# Android application not responding because of out of memory

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I am developing an android app and now I've found out that my app works fine only in devices with API 22 and higher. In all devices(virtual) with API less than 22 it crashes (not responding) almost immediately after start. 
I guess it happens because of out of memory.

If I look at tab Android Monitor (in Android Studio) on "Memory" diagram I can see 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvP4S.png), and
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRWih.png)

It looks like android has enough memory but just doesn't have time to allocate

How to find exact place on my code where it happens?

Log:

```
E/eglCodecCommon: writeFully: failed: Bad address

I/ActivityManager: Killing 1600:com.android.onetimeinitializer/u0a10 (adj 15): empty #17

W/libprocessgroup: failed to open /acct/uid_10010/pid_1600/cgroup.procs: No such file or directory

W/ActivityManager: Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!

I/InputDispatcher: Application is not responding: Window{32b75f14 u0 .MainActivity}.  It has been 5006.9ms since event, 5006.7ms since wait started.  Reason: Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 11.  Wait queue head age: 5549.6ms.

I/WindowManager: Input event dispatching timed out sending to .MainActivity.  Reason: Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 11.  Wait queue head age: 5549.6ms.

I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1927 SIG: 3

I/art:Thread[5,tid=1934,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xef70d400,peer=0x12c00080,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3

I/art: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 764 SIG: 3
I/art: Thread[5,tid=771,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xef70d400,peer=0x12c02080,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3

E/Sensors: Select fail, disconnect all clients (errno=4)

I/art: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1081 SIG: 3
10-15 14:59:59.410 1081-1089/com.android.phone I/art: Thread[5,tid=1089,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xef70d400,peer=0x12c00080,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3

I/art: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
10-15 14:59:59.477 764-785/system_process I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1050 SIG: 3

I/art: Thread[5,tid=1057,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xef70d400,peer=0x12c00080,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3

I/art: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 868 SIG: 3

I/art: Thread[5,tid=876,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xef70d400,peer=0x12c00080,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3

I/art: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'

I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 39859(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 15(316KB) LOS objects, 33% free, 7MB/11MB, paused 367us total 18.175ms

E/ActivityManager: ANR in projectName
                                                             PID: 1927
                                                             Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 11.  Wait queue head age: 5549.6ms.)

Load: 0.19 / 0.05 / 0.02

CPU usage from 9247ms to 0ms ago:

2.3% 125/adbd: 0.1% user + 2.2% kernel / faults: 2072 minor

1.2% 764/system_server: 0.4% user + 0.8% kernel / faults: 239 minor

1.1% 1927/prjectName: 0.8% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 731 minor

0.3% 303/local_opengl: 0% user + 0.3% kernel

0% 301/vinput: 0% user + 0% kernel

0.1% 1//init: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 9 minor

0.1% 8/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 0.1% kernel

0.1% 749/surfaceflinger: 0% user + 0.1% kernel

0.1% 1112/com.android.launcher3: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 377 minor

0.1% 1820/com.android.defcontainer: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 200 minor

1.5% TOTAL: 0.3% user + 1% kernel + 0% softer

CPU usage from 1802ms to 2307ms later with 99% awake:

3.9% 764/system_server: 0% user + 3.9% kernel / faults: 4 minor

1.4% TOTAL: 0.4% user + 0.4% kernel + 0.4% softirq
```

Comment: There's a library called LeakCanary. Never used it, but seen it mentioned around

Comment: Are we speaking of real devices? Don't forget that older systems are usually quite correlated with less memory so it's hard to isolate the reason. Check it in the emulator. When creating your AVD you can choose how much memory you give it. Load an image of API 16 or something with 4 or more GB, you'll see if it still happens.

Comment: Very unlikely that it is related to memory. Just try to debugging your app on a device with lower api levels. Also there should be a stack trace of the exception which caused your app to crash in the log. It should tell you what exactly the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

How to find exact place on my code where it happens? - Debug!

After deep debugging I guess I've found what was wrong.
The problem was that I used a custom ImageView and It took too much memory, so I will try to improve my custom ImageView.